# tweepy get media url from json response

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I want to get twitter image URL from its JSON response. I used a python script.below is the code.

```
import re
import tweepy
import sys
consumer_key = 'xxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token ='xxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
media_files = set()
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline,screen_name='@yyyyy').items(250):
    media = status.entities.get('media', [])
    if(len(media) > 0):
            media_files.add(media[0]['media_url'])
            url=status._json['media_url']
            print(url)
```

I need to sperate image URLs from JSON response and print it. It shows an error message as below.

`url=status._json['media_url']
  KeyError: 'media_url'`

Answer (score 4):

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline,screen_name='@yyyyy').items(250):
    if 'media' in status.entities:
        for image in status.entities['media']:
            print(image['media_url'])
```